# How to treat std::pair as two separate variables?

Tags: c++, std

There are a few functions in the standard library, such as [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert), which return a `std::pair`. At times it would be convenient to have that populate two different variables corresponding to the halves of the pair. Is there an easy way to do that?

```
std::map<int,int>::iterator it;
bool b;
magic(it, b) = mymap.insert(std::make_pair(42, 1));
```

I'm looking for the `magic` here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) from the `<tuple>` header is what you want.

```
std::tie(it, b) = mymap.insert(std::make_pair(42, 1));
```

"`magic`" :)

Note: This is a C++11 feature.

Comment: Another hidden gem from C++11! Thanks. And note that you need to `#include <tuple>` to use it.

Answer (score 16):

In C++17, you can use structured bindings. 
So you don't have to declare the variables first:

```
auto [it, b] = mymap.insert(std::make_pair(42, 1));
```

Comment: I just spotted this construct in the code base I'm working with.  Blew me away with how simple it was.

Answer (score 0):

In C++03, you must write like this:

```
std::pair< map<int, int>::iterator, bool > res = mymap.insert(std::make_pair(42, 1));
```

Comment: Yes, it should be obvious that you can create a `pair` variable to hold a `pair` return value. I was looking for an alternative.

Comment: In C++03, you can use `boost::tie`. It's only "minor magic" :)